# How can I use JSON to fetch a single piece of data from a webpage

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am using JSON to retrieve stock market data from an API (FMP cloud) for my Google Sheets spreadsheet, but don't know how to fetch a specific piece of data off of the API webpage. Here are the contents of the webpage I'm trying to pull from:

```
[ {
  "symbol" : "AMC",
  "name" : "AMC Entertainment Holdings, Inc.",
  "price" : 5.60000000,
  "changesPercentage" : -0.18000000,
  "change" : -0.01000000,
  "dayLow" : 5.55000000,
  "dayHigh" : 5.97000000,
  "yearHigh" : 20.36000000,
  "yearLow" : 1.91000000,
  "marketCap" : 1898808704.00000000,
  "priceAvg50" : 4.95848460,
  "priceAvg200" : 4.37841750,
  "volume" : 39477325,
  "avgVolume" : 120395740,
  "exchange" : "NYSE",
  "open" : 5.72000000,
  "previousClose" : 5.61000000,
  "eps" : -34.81800000,
  "pe" : null,
  "earningsAnnouncement" : "2020-11-02T16:15:00.000+0000",
  "sharesOutstanding" : 339072983,
  "timestamp" : 1613160110
} ]
```

If I use the cell script `=IMPORTJSON("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey", "/price","")` (I substituted out my real API key) it fetches all data with the word "price" in it, meaning price, priceAvg50, and priceAvg200. It looks like this:

```
    Avg50   Avg200
5.59    4.9584846   4.3784175
```

If I just want price, which is the first piece of data (5.59), how should I modify the script in the cell? Hopefully this question makes sense. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about `IMPORTJSON` you are using, if the structure of the data is always the same, how about using the script of `const IMPORTJSON = url => JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())[0].price;`? In this case, please put a formula of `=IMPORTJSON("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey")` to a cell.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. When I try this, it restricts what I can fetch to just the price. All cells with script looking to fetch other things come up as an error. Is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my comment, from `If I just want price, which is the first piece of data (5.59), how should I modify the script in the cell?`, I proposed it. About `When I try this, it restricts what I can fetch to just the price. All cells with script looking to fetch other things come up as an error. Is there a way to bypass that?` in your replying, can you provide the sample output you expect? By this, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: No problem at all, I appreciate you taking the time to help me. A sample output would be two cells. In cell 1, I would write `=IMPORTJSON("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey", "/price", "noHeaders")` which ideally would show me the price of the stock. In cell 2, I would write `=IMPORTJSON("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey", "/changesPercentage", "noHeaders")`, which would show me the percent change of the stock price.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your 2 reply comments, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: That's perfect, I think I understand it now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem dude, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following 2 reply comments,

> When I try this, it restricts what I can fetch to just the price. All cells with script looking to fetch other things come up as an error. Is there a way to bypass that?

> A sample output would be two cells. In cell 1, I would write `=IMPORTJSON("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey", "/price", "noHeaders")` which ideally would show me the price of the stock. In cell 2, I would write `=IMPORTJSON("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey", "/changesPercentage", "noHeaders")`, which would show me the percent change of the stock price.

I understood your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the JSON data in your question by giving the property names.

Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current script of `IMPORTJSON`, if the structure of the data from your URL is always the same, how about directly creating a script for the URL you want to use?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet.

```
function SAMPLE(url, keys) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
  return [keys.split(",").map(k => obj[0][k.trim()] || "")];
}
```

- When you use this script, please put `=SAMPLE("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey", "price")` and `=SAMPLE("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey", "changesPercentage")`.
- If you want to retrive the multiple values by one custom forumula, please put `=SAMPLE("https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/quote/AMC/?apikey=examplekey", "price,changesPercentage")`.

  - When above sample data is used, this formula returns `5.6, -0.18` to a row.
- If the property name which is not existing in the data from URL is given, the empty value is returned.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Answer (score 0):

```
function hexhead() {
  const d=JSON.parse('[ {  "symbol" : "AMC",  "name" : "AMC Entertainment Holdings, Inc.",  "price" : 5.60000000,  "changesPercentage" : -0.18000000,  "change" : -0.01000000,  "dayLow" : 5.55000000,  "dayHigh" : 5.97000000,  "yearHigh" : 20.36000000,  "yearLow" : 1.91000000,  "marketCap" : 1898808704.00000000,  "priceAvg50" : 4.95848460,  "priceAvg200" : 4.37841750,  "volume" : 39477325,  "avgVolume" : 120395740,  "exchange" : "NYSE",  "open" : 5.72000000,  "previousClose" : 5.61000000,  "eps" : -34.81800000,  "pe" : null,  "earningsAnnouncement" : "2020-11-02T16:15:00.000+0000",  "sharesOutstanding" : 339072983,  "timestamp" : 1613160110} ]');
  console.log(d[0].timestamp)
}

7:12:44 PM  Notice  Execution started
7:12:44 PM  Info    1613160110
7:12:45 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```